Pkcs11Interop with Softhsm and Docker - Method C_Initialize returned CKR_GENERAL_ERROR
I have a dotnet8 console app that works fine with SoftHsmv2 on windows.
I then dockerised the console app with softhsm installed & intialised during docker build as below:
#noble tag for Ubuntu 24.04
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:8.0-noble AS base

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y softhsm2 libsofthsm2 opensc
RUN /usr/bin/softhsm2-util --init-token --slot 0 --label devtoken1 --pin 56789 --so-pin 12345

#etc..

I also configured the DllImportResolver for libdl.so.2 .
Also running the below command within the container works fine (docker exec ).
pkcs11-tool --module /usr/lib/softhsm/libsofthsm2.so -L

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
    Console.WriteLine("LibExists:" + File.Exists("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/softhsm/libsofthsm2.so"));//returns True

    SetupCustomDllImportResolver()

    var factories = new Pkcs11InteropFactories();
    using (var pkcs11Library = factories.Pkcs11LibraryFactory.LoadPkcs11Library(factories, SoftHsm2Manager.LibraryPath, AppType.SingleThreaded))
    {
        //etc...
    }
}

I get below error:
Unhandled exception. Net.Pkcs11Interop.Common.Pkcs11Exception: Method C_Initialize returned CKR_GENERAL_ERROR
   at Net.Pkcs11Interop.HighLevelAPI80.Pkcs11Library.Initialize(AppType appType)
   at Net.Pkcs11Interop.HighLevelAPI80.Pkcs11Library..ctor(Pkcs11InteropFactories factories, String libraryPath, AppType appType)
   at Net.Pkcs11Interop.HighLevelAPI80.Factories.Pkcs11LibraryFactory.LoadPkcs11Library(Pkcs11InteropFactories factories, String libraryPath, AppType appType)
   at Net.Pkcs11Interop.HighLevelAPI.Factories.Pkcs11LibraryFactory.LoadPkcs11Library(Pkcs11InteropFactories factories, String libraryPath, AppType appType)
   at SoftHsm.ConsoleApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in /src/Program.cs:line 14


Is there something in SoftHSM logs related to your calls?

I cant find /var/log/syslog. Where can i find the logs?

Check this issue: https://github.com/softhsm/SoftHSMv2/commit/9346a3793be8af9301de30ba58389e86c9584476

Also check that you have libp11-kit-dev installed. https://github.com/softhsm/SoftHSMv2/blob/develop/README.md#dependencies

i did but still no luck. thanks
